# Using Simple Dom Parser create more than one files

Tags: php

I am using php simple dom parser to get the table elements of and html page and then create file for each element.

This is my code:

```
<?php

 include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

 $html = file_get_html('test.html');

 foreach($html->find('table[id=backgroundTable]') as $element);

   $element = $html->save();

$html->save('result.html');
```

The problem I have at them moment is that it stores all the tables in this result.html file. 
What I need is the export results to be result1.html , result2.html . How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `foreach($html->find('table[id=backgroundTable]') as $element);` this line makes no sense

Comment: H bartek I am using this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I meant putting `;` at the end of `foreach` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this, so in each loop the `$i` will be increased:

```
$html = file_get_html('test.html');
$i = 1;
foreach($html->find('table#backgroundTable') as $element) {
    str_get_html($element)->save('result' . $i . '.html');
    $i++;
}
```

So the results will be saved in `result1.html`, `result2.html` and so on.

Comment: better, but still not enough ;)

Comment: Missing `{` after `foreach` stmt

Comment: Thanks but it was a copy paste and a typo only :-)

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha Is there a way to extend this and create a screenshot as well?